# Scala/Play Framework: Passing a view to a view

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this line of code:

```
Ok(views.html.main("Title",views.html.userShow(user)))
```

According to the debugger *views.html.userShow(user)* returns a Html object.

*main2* starts with

```
@(title: String)(content: play.twirl.api.Html)
```

Now I get the error message:

> too many arguments for method apply: (title: String)(content:
>   play.twirl.api.Html)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object
>   main2

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration for the `main` view is using curried parameters:

```
@(title: String)(content: play.twirl.api.Html)
```

Which means you'd have to pass them like this:

```
Ok(views.html.main("Title")(views.html.userShow(user)))
```

The error is thrown because you're trying to pass too many parameters to the first grouping.

Alternatively, change the parameters of the `main` view to not be curried:

```
@(title: String, content: play.twirl.api.Html)
```